# Failing hard at OOP in python

Tags: python, oop, object

This represents a simple class, that I have made to try and practice OOP.

```
import csv
import logging


class LoaderCSV:

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

        if file is None:
            logging.warning('Missing input file.')

    def load(self):
        with open(self.file) as f:
            holder = csv.reader(f)
            file_data = list(holder)

        return file_data
```

What happens is when I call this class with:

```
data = LoaderCSV.load(input_file)
```

I get

```
line 14, in load 
with open(self.file) as f:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'file'
```

I must be messing something up, but can't understand what. My previous attempt worked just fine this way. I just don't understand why

```
self.file
```

does not pass the value, assigned to the argument, when it is defined under `__init__`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're calling an instance method as a static method, so your filename is being passed in instead of `self`. The proper way to do this would be like:

```
loader = LoaderCSV(input_file)
data = loader.load()
```

This will pass in `loader` as the `self` parameter, allowing you to access the file name in the object's `file` field.

Check out the Python documentation on [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) for more information.

Comment: So is that caused by the __init__ function? I mean if there is init I must pass the arguments to the class itself first and then call the method just to fire it up? Can this work without init? Thanks all for answering :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `LoaderCSV` object first, then call the `load` method on that object.

```
loader = LoaderCSV(input_file)
data = loader.load()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to use the instance method `load` is to make an instance of your class, and then call the method on that class. Like this:

```
myloader = LoaderCSV(input_file)
data = myloader.load()
```

or succinctly:

```
data = LoaderCSV(input_file).load()
```